# Cotree Generation

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a co-graph like the one attached[image: s] as an input what are the steps that I have to follow in order to generate its co-tree? Is there a step-by-step algorithm to do that?

Comment: There are only 2 possible operations to build a cograph: disjoint union and complement. What was the last operation for this graph?

Comment: @Dmitry This graph was randomly generated using python's NetworkX functionalities.

Comment: It doesn't matter how it was generated. For this graph, only one iteration can be the last one.

Comment: @Dmitry Judging by your comments I understand that in order to generate a co-tree from a co-graph you have to know exactly the steps followed when it was generated?

Comment: Yes. It follows from definition of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cograph#Cotrees (the nodes of types 1 are essentially composition of 3 operations: complement + union + complement). Note that 1) there may be multiple co-trees (e.g. consider a graph without edges) 2) it's trivial to decide which operation was the last for a cograph (like in case of this graph)

Comment: @Dmitry This is totally true. Yet, since this information was not available in my case I moved on to an algorithm as described in pg.7 on this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.08517.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3O7OlyDed0m9GvNH_lewEf1VPQx1PXiOivd201w_9tnAI1p07Kh7I-r-I Although it has some ambiguous points.